# How can I save images on the web with drag and drop?

Tags: firefox

In firefox on Mac OSX I usually save images by dragging them from the browser to the folder I want to save them to. I prefer this method compared to navigating through the file browser as it is much faster.

When I do the same in Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 it saves a link to the image instead of the actual image. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: Please note this is from Tumblr.com

Answer (score 5):

This is part of the basic feature set of Chrome and Firefox:

- LMB-drag: Create a `.desktop` launcher / Save link
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ LMB-drag: Save picture

LMB = left mouse button

Comment: Strangely enough, I am having the same issues on Windows. Ctrl+Drag worked for me as well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there is a much easier way to save the images.

Which way I mean?? This one here:

1. right-click the picture
2. in the up-popping menue, select "save as" and select the folder, where the picture shall be saved.

Or another easy way:

go to your menue and open "screenshot" and take a screenshot of this picture and save it.

Greetings
Andrea

Comment: surely you're trolling... of course it's easier to drag the image and drop it into an open file manager window.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the firefox extension  Drag & DropZones. It appears to do everything you want and more.

You can assign a context menu action like "Copy File" to a drop zone.

Comment: Only works with search menus in context, does not work thanks for trying

Comment: @Gary Wheadon Have you tried the latest version? look carefully. You can assign a context menu action like "Copy File" to a drop zone.

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer this alternative, a [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-image-in-folder/?src=search) which creates a new context menu item: "Save image in folder"

You can add as many folders as you like to the menu item's dropdown, so it's basically the same as choosing "Save image as" without choosing a file format or folder.

So `Right-click > Save image in folder > YourCustomPicFolder`

EDIT: Or you might install a dock like `Docky` from the repositories. That dock supports saving items in this way I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging images from the browser and dropping them into Nautilus only works if:

- the element being dragged is `<img/>` and not `<a href="..."><img /></a>`
- the browser is firefox.

in all other scenarios, you'll get variations on a text file with an url or a datauri of the image.